# I suspect headhunter company is lying to me. How to contact customers directly?

Tags: recruitment, germany

*(Update: problem solved, *H* and the agents are probably clear)*

---

I am applying for my next job here, in Germany. I have been in contact with a headhunting company and applying for jobs through them.

The situation is the following:

```
   A
  /
Ha
Hb
  \
   B--C
```

"H" is the headhunter company. I am in contact with 2 of their agents there, name them *Ha* and *Hb*. *Ha* is the contact person for company *A*, where I've jad a very good job interview. It had the best atmosphere I ever had in Germany. After that I've feel I have more than 90% chance to be accepted.

*Hb* is the contact person for company *B*. They will send me in outsourcing to company *C*. *C* is a bad name in the area, and I know the company and I know that it is bad to work there.

In company *B*, I also had a job interview. They didn't even know my CV, and from their test questions was it clearly visible that they highly underestimate my skills. They also gave me some questions about a technology which doesn't even exist in my CV. Other than those things, the interview seemed to run relatively well, but I estimated my chance to get a job offer below 50%.

At this headhunter company *H* each agent is responsible only for their own customers, so *Ha* is responsible for company *A* and *Hb* is only responsible for things about company *B*.

Now, *Hb* contacted me with results: *A* has rejected me, but *B* has accepted. *It was communicated to me by the agent Hb*, even though it isn't his responsibility.

Agent *Hb* didn't want to explain me the rejection reason from *A*, but after I persisted he said that they wanted somebody with team-leading experience. Team-leading wasn't even mentioned in *A*'s  original job description, and also not on the job interview.

I suspect, that in the reality, both *A* and *B* have accepted me, but the headhunter *H* wants to optimize his economic results by sending me to *B* (for further outsourcing), and sending someone else to *A*. I know that *A* is a high-level, important customer of *H*, while *B* is not so, mainly because *B* only hires to outsource and *A* only has direct-hire jobs.

Considering that *H* could at least find me a job, I think it would be unprofessional to do contact *A* behind their back. But, I think it is important to at least check to see that *A* also wanted to employ me.

I am thinking of simply calling *A* behind the back of *Ha*, disguising at as a nice "I am really sorry you decided not to hire me for this position. I hope you'll keep me in mind in the future." talk. But in the reality, I would be trying to find out what their *real* decision was.

Is this a reasonable thing to do? How could I check with *A* politely, without doing something that would make me probably forever blacklisted by *H*?

---

*Update:* I asked *Ha* about my rejection from *A*, and he gave me a more detailed version of what *Hb* told me. This means that *Hb* wasn't going behind *Ha*'s back, but it could still mean that *H* is lying to me and *A*. However, *Ha* earlier mentioned to me that the *H* and *A* have a longstanding good relationship. It's not likely *H* would risk that relationship by lying about me.

Despite that, I am thinking about writing to the bosses at *A*, but this time really about to trying to make a longer contact with them. I will first ask *Ha*'s permission to do that.

Comment: Applying directly and getting accepted directly is *very* common in Germany. Headhunters and Outsourcing costs a bunch of money and only huge corporations can afford to have a staff of outsiders.

Comment: @nvoigt Well, I've seen *some* direct employment offers already, but somehow I, my coworkers I was friendly with, and people I know here, somehow didn't find their way to their job on this way. Things are working normally so, that people works somewhere 2 years in outsourcing (externe Mitarbeiter), and then he gets an offer for direct employment. Or not. This 2 years is only because of the fights of the reds (Betriebsrat). Of course if the company/department has financial problems, they are fired in the first line.

Comment: General advice: What you are talking about sounds more like _Zeitarbeit_ (an agency for temporary work) than an actual headhunting company. I believe that if you are in a field that required highly trained people (let's say IT or engineering) as opposed to working in a warehouse or delivering parcels, the best course of action is to contact companies directly in general instead of going through an agency. If your resume looks good and your application conform with German expectations, it will work eventually.

Comment: Have you spoken to Ha since Hb told you that you had been rejected? I can see Hb lying to you that you've been rejected (so that he gets the commission rather than Ha), I think it's less likely that the agency as a whole are favouring one job over the other.

Comment: @simbabque I am in IT. And my practical chances to get a job are much lower as it seems. Germans are very polite (by default), quite secretive (by default), and they have a paranoid fear from being sued (which is unsaid). Thus, I have no way to know, why is it so, nobody says it to me. If they say anything, is inconclusive (for example, they wanted somebody for teamleading while they didn't even asked for it on the job interview). Maybe I could ask for tips & tricks in a new question, it is an interesting topic.

Comment: @thelem Uhm... I would be really sorry if I would let Hb to be fired. He is also foreigner, so he will find next job also very hardly... but I will do this. (Ha is native.) I hope this little trouble won't cause tragic consequence for him. Thank you very much the good idea!

Comment: I wouldn't generalize it like that, but there sure are some companies that don't know what they need or want, or where HR is not up to speed or not qualified IT-wise to communicate properly what the IT-department wants. If you are a decent enough developer though, we grow dev jobs on trees in the Berlin startup-sphere right now. In fact, most startup companies have way more international employees than Germans. I know companies where the only one speaking German is the HR.

Comment: @MorningStar If Hb is lying and being deceptive, then he deserves to be fired. Don't feel bad for him.

Comment: @simbabque I am not in Berlin, I am in a local center with fewer population as 1 million (and it is not NRW). One of the significant advantages of `A` had been that they are in Munich.

Comment: @DavidK O.k. Next problem: I don't know, where are they sitting, by I suspect they are in a single-room office (Großraumbüro). And, if Hb didn't lie, making a groundless suspiction would negative consequence for me. So, how to contant `Ha` and test what was `A`s real dicision, without the feeling that I don't trust `Hb`?

Comment: @MorningStar Just take the same approach you planned with A and hide it in a question. Go to Ha and say "Hb said that A rejected me, but didn't have a great explanation as to why. Do you have any other information as to why they might have rejected me?"

Comment: @DavidK He gave explanation, but only for persisted query, and it was inconclusive. I can't say that he didn't. Maybe I could politely ask Ha that what other reasons can he yet imagine. Companies rejecting applicants say the reason only rarely. But I've seen relative clearly, that `Ha` and `Hb` are regularly racing for me, which I found at the time quite wonderful.

Comment: @MorningStar I doubt they would fire Hb over it, but even if they did it would be his lie that got him fired, not what you said.

Comment: Do you think H would object if you connected with one of you interviewers at A on LinkedIn? You could use the connect message to say thanks for the interview, sorry to hear I didn't have enough team leadership for that role but I'd still love to work there, please let me or H know if you have any other roles I could fill, etc. Again (like David K suggests) just spell out the facts as you know them, and let them contradict you as necessary.

Comment: Forget all this Machiavellian intrigue. Simply call Ha up and ask why you were rejected. If he asks why you're calling him say that you're his contact with the company, and hold him responsible to explain what happened. Remember that to them you represent money. Stop acting like a scared schoolchild and act like a grownup. You want an explanation, so go get it. Furthermore, if you still suspect them lying, pick up the phone and call Company A. Simply ask for interview feedback, and go from there. Don't leave your fate in the hands of people in whose interest it might be to screw you over

Comment: And update the question to let us know how it goes!

Comment: @AndreiROM Done. `H`, `Ha` and `Hb` seem clear, and probably `A` was the black boy. Probably they've simply found a better applicant.

Comment: @DavidK I don't agree that the removed info had been irrelevant, but I agree that the question was too long, and probably didn't pass perfectly the site standards. Next to that, I am very happy and thankful for your answer, suggestions and opinions. Thus, no problem - and thank you very much again.

Comment: Please don't abuse code markup like this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, to answer a different question, I would say that it is more likely that Hb is lying to you than that H is lying to you. I would start by contacting Ha first to verify that you were rejected. If you don't want this to come off as accusatory, hide it in a question.

> Hb said that Company A rejected me, but didn't have a good explanation as to why. Do you have any more information from Company A about why they would have rejected me? I thought my interview went very well.

If he also says that you were rejected, then I think it is very likely he is telling the truth. Often at recruiting companies you have your quota per recruiter, and him giving you over to company B doesn't help him in any way.

If you are still suspicious and feel the desire to contact A, then do so, but keep in mind that it may be in breach of your contract with H, and you could be removed from their list. That is a risk you take. And make if you do this, make sure that you are still approaching it as trying to figure out if you can improve, or asking if they would still consider you for future positions.

Never accuse anyone of lying - just tell them you were told you were rejected and let them respond accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I have no contract to H, but it doesn't mean that they wouldn't be removed from their list.

Comment: @MorningStar Note that this answer avoids some of your own suggested actions **which are based on assumptions**. That is always a bad idea. David's course of action replaces assumptions with facts.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer and comments helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: If you don't feel you can trust someone and you don't need to do business with that someone, don't do business with that someone.

If you contact A directly to ask for the rejection reason, you might lose standing with the headhunter, but that isn't even necessarily the case. Even if you lose standing, they won't sabotage the offer by B, because they still want to get that money from company B.

The only case where you could possibly face negative consequences for contacting A is if you absolutely need H to get a job in the future, other than the job at B.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not in a position where I could choose, which job offer I accept. H worked hardily to find a job for me (next to these, I had 2 other offers as well. In one of them, the interview view the customer will happen in 3 hours), other agents hasn't, this makes them important in my eyes.

Comment: Because of this "outsourcing to a bad name" offer, probably not I am the only applicant trying to avoid `B`. `A` is a good job, but only for me: they don't use really useful technologies in the future, but they use techs I love. But other programmers don't have this affinity to `A`s techs, so their offer is good only in my eyes. Next to that they are in a much better city, it was another reason, what made `A` a dream job for me.

Comment: @MorningStar which puts you in the "need to do business with that someone" clause, unfortunately. Personally I'd contact A directly. If it turns out they want you (which is unlikely) H will still get their finders fee, if they don't want you, you can still get job B. At worst, H will stop looking for other opportunities past job B - it's up to you if you want to take that risk.

Comment: Another info: one of the reasons of the very good outcome of the interview by `A` was that they've also seen, that I love their techs. The interview went with their Boss, i.e. who directly decides about the recruiting, and he very clearly signed that he wants me.

Comment: Now that I have my offer from B, rejecting it would be surely a bad thing before H. But if I have my offer from A and also from B, maybe H (as collective entity) could it find better if they send me to B, for example because they can show other acceptable applicant to A, while probably only few want to work for B. And although I seem unlucky in this country, other programmers probably _have_ the choice to select the offers.

Comment: @MorningStar Your thinking is correct. Placing 2 candidates makes them more money than placing one. But lying destroys their reputation, and I have previously turned down candidates I wanted to hire because I found even better candidates. I'd contact A to ask for the reason, but I'd do so primarily because I'd be interested in the reason, not because I'm sure they'll hire me if I call them.

Comment: Good idea, but if H will know it, it will harm my reputation before them. I know, partially because of the secretive nature of the country, companies hiring by head hunters have mostly fewer information from the job market as me (after a lot of job interviews and going everywhere with open eyes). But they didn't give me their name cards. `Ha` said, they have a long, good contact by them. But I was contacted originally by `Hb`, `Ha` has regularly tried toke me over from him. Doing this, maybe `Ha` has violated their internal rules, and he wants to fix it by giving me to `Hb` back.

Comment: You had right. But, what I didn't mention: `Ha` said to me (before the appearance of this whole problem), that they have a long contact with `A`. Betraying a longstanding customer is unimaginable in Germany, but saying to an applicant that "you are ok, we want you", and then stepping back is quite common. This cleans `H` and the agents with high probability. Anyways, I can't enough thank you your answer!